# Get JSON with AngularJS via PHP GET Page

Tags: routes, port, portal

I have a problem with JSON and AngularJS. My situation is:

I have:
- app.js (AngularJS app)
- GET.PHP
- demo.html

In app.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyWholeWorld', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("GET.php")
      .success(function(response) {$scope.Menu = response.records;});});
```

In GET.php:

```html
include("http://localhost/JSON.php");
```

And in demo.html file is the way binding data.

The JSON.php will echo JSON.
If I change GET.php to JSON.php in AngularJS app ==> I get the JSON.

But if I do like above, I get nothing.

The reason I want to do like this is: I have many PHP files to return JSON. And the GET.php will become a reader to categorize PHP JSON file.

EX: app.js (GET.php?Table=Hello) - GET.php proceeds and include("Hello.php") to return JSON from Hello.php

Please help me to find the solution of this.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could be having a logical problem. Try implement your hello.php script like a class or a function...

hello.php

```
class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

include hello.php in your GET.php, and then call the function appropriately.

GET.php

```
include ('hello.php');

switch ($_PARAM['Table'])
{
   case "Hello":  return Foo::aStaticMethod(); break;
}
```